# Javascript - Loading multiplescripts on page dynamically with dependencies

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a page constructor made all with javascript. The problem comes when I dynamically add 2 scripts on the page that depends on the other. In this example I am loading the jQuery from the CDN, and in the second script I call a jQuery function to modify the text of the title, and, because the first is not already loaded, I get the error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

What is the best way? Maybe wait to load the next script until previous one gets loaded?

One tip, I dont want to use external libraries like RequireJS (this would need to be updating the page everytime the plugin updates, and it would never be possible in this case).

---

**EXAMPLE**

Thats my **JS classes**:

```
NS.Script = function(nHasCode, nType, nSrc, nContent){
  this.hasCode = nHasCode;
  this.src = nSrc;
  this.type = nType;
  this.content = nContent;
};

NS.Page = function(){
  this.id;
  this.isIndex;
  this.title;
  this.metas = [];
  this.links = [];
  this.styles = [];
  this.scripts = [];
  this.body;
};

NS.Page.prototype.addScript = function(hasCode, type, src = null, content = null){
  var aux = new NS.Script(hasCode, type, src, content);
  var pageScripts = this.scripts;
  pageScripts.push(aux);
};

NS.Pages = {
  load: function(page){
    //document.write(page.body);
    document.body.innerHTML = page.body;
    document.title = page.title;
    page.scripts.forEach(function(pageScript) {
      if(pageScript.hasCode){
        document.write("<script type="+pageScript.type+">"+pageScript.content+"<\/script>");
      }else{
        var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
        s.setAttribute( 'type', pageScript.type );
        s.setAttribute( 'src', pageScript.src );
        if (s.readyState){  //IE
          script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (s.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    s.readyState == "complete"){
              s.onreadystatechange = null;
              //maybe here I have to call the script load of every dependance
            }
          };
        } else {  //Others
          s.onload = function(){
            //callback();
            //maybe here I have to call the script load of every dependance
          };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( s );
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Finally I **create a page** and add **two scripts**:

```
var pagina = NS.Pages.new("Prueba", "Pagina 1");
pagina.title = "Page title";
pagina.isIndex = true;
pagina.body = "<h1 id='title'>Page title with H1</h1><p>This could be a paragraph</p>";
pagina.addScript(false, 'text/javascript', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js');
pagina.addScript(true, 'text/javascript', null, "$('#title').text('The new title configured with jQuery');");
NS.Pages.load(pagina);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a chicken and egg problem. It stems from the fact that dynamically inserted `<script>` tags get a default "async" property and are executed in unpredictable order. According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), you can request them to be synced:

```
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.setAttribute( 'type', pageScript.type );
s.setAttribute( 'src', pageScript.src );
s.async = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your try, but still cant work. I am thinking on queue the scripts and make a function that loads in order, everyone one is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadJavaScriptSync(filePath)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", filePath, false); // 'false': synchronous.
    req.send(null);

    var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    newScriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
    newScriptElement.text = req.responseText;
    headElement.appendChild(newScriptElement);
}

loadJavaScriptSync("file1.js");
loadJavaScriptSync("file2.js");
</script>
```

Code snippet taken from: http://trevweb.me.uk/javascripthtml-synchronous-and-asynchronous-loading/

Comment: That is a great way to do it, but what happens if the second script is not a file, could be like `<script type="text/javascript"> alert('Hello'); </script>`. I use `document.write()` to load that script, but if req havent finished, it will throws an error.

Comment: Check the link. It has covered your scenario.